# Display a code snippet based on a taxonomy term

Tags: 7, nodes

I am trying to build a node file for a content type in Drupal 7.59. I have for example a field for a taxonomy term. There is only 2 terms Expert and Guest.
I want to display something on the node if this term reference choice is marked as Expert.

So I need to figure out how to write a line that checks for the value of the taxonomy term and then if it matches expert then it displays something but if it is guest it doesn't.

The field I have setup in my content type is:

- Name of field: author type
- Machine Name: field_author_type
- Field Type: Term reference

The root taxonomy term is Author Type and the two terms are Expert and Guest.
Does anyone know how to accomplish this? I hovered over the taxonomy term I wanted to reference and it was /taxonomy/term/57/ Is 57 the actual number or do I find it elsewhere?

So far I have this which is not much and it doesn't work so it is wrong. I am really sucky at php.

```
<?php if ($content['field_authors_type']->taxonomy[57]): ?>
    Put what you want to display here
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: So you're using a node template file, like node.tpl.php? If you want to check the value of a field, you can use something like this $content["field_authors_type"]["#items"][0]["tid"].

Answer (score 0):

The value you're looking for would be stored like so

```
$content["field_authors_type"]["#items"][0]["tid"]
```

You could, if you wanted to be tidier, put this `if` statement in your theme's template.php in a `template_preprocess_node` or `template_preprocess_page` function (more on that here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7.x).

You would store your boolean value `$variables['author_is_expert']` and then in your node.tpl.php, you can just use `if ($author_is_expert)`